# Getting an interview invitation for an internship instead of the job

Tags: interviewing, job-search, internship, title

I got an email invitation for an interview, but as I recall, I applied for an actual job, not an internship. I wouldn't mind an internship though since I'm also looking for a junior position. Should I restate to them about my actual intentions of applying for a job instead of an internship?

I had a similar experience before and I told the previous company that I am actually applying for a job, and I haven't got any news from them since. What should I do this time?

Comment: Do you qualify for the non-intern position? They may be filtering based on qualifications and decided to extent an offer for a different position they feel you may qualify for.

Comment: "as I recall, I did applied for a job application" - How? If by email, surely you have a copy? If not, maybe you need to keep better records (that's advice, not criticism(

Comment: How big of a money difference is there between "intern" and "job"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes companies made an intership from a job because the project is in its early phases, nobody really knows what will happen for this project. it will also depend on the departement finances at this time of the year ( maybe they think they can hire somebody for 6 month, and finally found there is not engouh money).

In your situation : if you are hungry for the position because it is a good company and you don't have really have other good option you can go to the interview and :

-Take the internship and do a goodjob and hope they hire you at the end.

-Show that you are the best candidate, but explain you are young and need to pay your rent and you try to change the intership into a several month contract at minimum wedge. (this is risky, but i have seen it work, for job that required skills on a not famous sofware, the applicant knew he had the perfect qualifications).

**Should I restate to them about my actual intentions of applying for a job instead of an internship?**

-> confirm on the phone that they didn't make a mistake : "hello dear HR, i received the internship but i apply for a job, would you mind confirm if it is the same position or if there was some changes internally?"

-> if it is not too far from your home ( you don't need to spend a lot of money for the travel), you just go to the interview and make the best of it.You are young, whatever is the result of the interview you will have more interview experience which is good for the futur interviews.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the recruiter hasn't considered that you for the job you applied for, but they see potential and think you are suitable with the Junior position / Internship which often happens. I have worked for employers who value Interns highly and give them opportunities to apply for future job openings.

> I wouldn't mind an internship though since I'm also looking for a junior position.

You need to firstly find out whether or not you definitely applied for the job and not the internship otherwise if you're mistaken you will look like you haven't paid attention, although as you have stated you wouldn't mind the Junior position so you could take the internship to add to your experience.

Once you have the internship, you can always enquire and look to undertake future job postings, only this time you'll have more experience in the job and experience with that company.